# Why can't the Iterator.next() method in ES6 just return the value?

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6

To implement an iterator in ES6, one has to implement a method `next` that returns a structure like this: `{value: Any, done: Boolean}`.

I understand that the `done` field is necessary to signal that there are *no more values*, but I don't understand why the iterator itself couldn't simply have a field/method to do the same job.

As it stands, a new object needs to be created on every iteration step as a defensive measure against potential bugs (*e.g. if someone decides to keep a reference to the result*) and it seems like a waste of resources, but surely they had a reason to choose this interface.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]

The most obvious possible alternative implementation example I could think of:

```
function iter(arr) {
    var idx = 0, done = false;
    return {
        isDone: function() {
            return done;
        },
        next: function() {
            if(idx >= arr.length - 1) {
                done = true;
            }
            return arr[idx++];
        }
    };
}

var i = iter([1, 2, 3, 4]);

while(!i.isDone()) {
    console.log(i.next());
}
```

Comment: _but I don't understand why the iterator itself couldn't simply have a field/method to do the same job_ - can you show how it could be implemented?

Comment: because it's a standard.

Comment: Java chose to use a `hasNext()` method, if that's the kind of thing you're describing. This kind of question is difficult to answer, because unless the primary sources exist for your exact question, there's no way for us to know for sure why that standard was chosen.

Comment: @4castle even I had this question when I encountered Iterators. What if it returns only value and Iterator has a property that holds current index. So all we would need is `iterator.next()` and if index is required, `iterator.index()` or `iterator.index`

Comment: @Maximus: 
`function iter(arr) {
 var idx = 0, done = false;
 return {
  isDone: function() {
   return done;
  },
  next: function() {
   if(idx >= arr.length - 1) {
    done = true;
   }
   return arr[idx++];
  }
 };
}

var i = iter([1, 2, 3, 4]);

while(!i.isDone()) {
 console.log(i.next());
}`

[edit]
That looks awful... how do I fix the formatting? :(

Comment: @Rajesh Sure, but indexes only apply to structures that have a specified ordering and finite size. Iterators don't have to be backed by a data structure with those qualities, so an index may not make sense in those cases.

Comment: It's pretty simple.  The iterator returns two pieces of information and the way you do that in Javascript is to return an object with two properties.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm asking about the reasoning behind the standard, not why I have to follow it to have working iterators.

Comment: @jfriend00 Try reading the question more attentively. What's unclear to me is why they had to return two values in the first place when there's a pretty obvious alternative that seems cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: SO is not a place to ask things like that. Please ask [TC-39](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm).

Comment: @4castle I meat something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ekqcfnbr/). Note, I know this is half-cooked and its just a sample

Comment: Your scheme (which you only just added to your question) requires two method calls vs. one method call in the current scheme.  If you want to know the "why" for all these design decisions, we can't help you here.  Go read archived mailing lists where the proposed standard was discussed or itnerview someone who worked on it.  This question is unlikely to be productive here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Object creation is unlikely to be cheaper than a method call, and in any case it could just be a field instead. 95% of the questions on this site could be answered by going through archived mailing lists. Perhaps someone has already done that and could offer an answer so that others don't have to go through the same. It looks to me like you have nothing of value to add to this discussion, so you choose to complain about the validity of the question instead.

Comment: _"Object creation is unlikely to be cheaper than a method call"_ It's much cheaper. A function call requires the creation of even more "objects" (environment etc.) e.g.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like a waste of resources

It's not really. Engines are quite good at optimising short-lived object allocation. On the other hand, your approach requires two method calls, which aren't free either.

> Object creation is unlikely to be cheaper than a method call

That might be where you're mistaken.

> Why had they to return two values in the first place when there's a pretty obvious alternative that seems cleaner and more efficient?

Well, it's clear why the two values are needed (an alternative would have been throwing an `IterationEnd` exception, but that was deemed *really* ugly). You always need both of them when iterating. So why would they choose two separate methods that always had to be called both (cumbersome and possibly error-prone), when there's a pretty obvious alternative that seems cleaner and more efficient?

For some discussion, see https://esdiscuss.org/topic/performance-of-iterator-next-as-specified.

Comment: Engines are also pretty good at optimizing trivial method calls. Unless the ES6 standard mandates optimizations that would make object creation more efficient, it doesn't make sense as a justification. Like I said, if that was a real concern, the iterator could have a `done` field instead of a method.

Comment: As for calling the alternative "cumbersome and error-prone", this makes no sense. Usage would be either identical (for ... of loop) or almost identical (iter.done instead of result.done, minus the unnecessary .value indirection) but without the ambiguity (do I own the result or did the implementer of this iterator decide to reuse the object?).

Comment: @user3026691 No, the ES6 standard does not mandate any optimisations, but it's implementation reality so that neither solution had any efficiency concerns. Regarding "error-prone and cumbersome", I meant more the definition of the methods rather than their consumption, as they'd have to share state and things could go wrong in between the method calls. If `.isDone()` is nothing but a getter everywhere, it becomes repetitive. So why not just return `done` from the `next` method where it is available anyway?

Comment: I don't really see how setting a flag where you would otherwise return `true` is any more cumbersome or error-prone. I think the real danger comes from an iterator implementer choosing to reuse a result object to save a few cycles and reduce GC activity (the latter could be significant in an interactive application). The former varies between implementations (try https://repl.it/ENaV on Chrome vs FF) while the latter is a problem in any GC'ed language for applications like games, even if object creation is fast.

Comment: @user3026691 Setting a flag is a side effect that can be avoided. It might get out of sync with your internal iteration condition, or if you choose to dynamically evaluate that condition every time then it requires duplication as you usually have to test it inside the `next` call as well - and if you already tested it there, simply returning that result from `next` is simpler (your demo is broken in that regard, it still increments the value after it is done when you call `next` again). Regarding GC, engines are expected to be able to allocate the result object on the stack (assuming no reuse)

Comment: Your argument makes no sense. An iterator already relies on 'next' mutating some internal state, of which a 'done' flag would be the most trivial piece. In any case you have a boolean value that you use to set a field. What's the difference between setting it in the result object and setting it in the iterator object? It's a trivial and purely mechanical transformation from one style to the other. The demo isn't broken. Both iterators have that behavior (which the standard allows), so I have no idea why you're trying to pick on that.

Comment: As for the GC thing, that's implementation-dependent at best, and for this reason anyone writing interactive applications would either avoid iterators altogether or make custom ones that reuse the result object. Both options are clearly less than ideal.

Comment: @user3026691 Yes, it's a simple mechanical transformation from one to another, however setting an extra field is less pure. The argument is that there is not really any advantage using your approach, and the specced one was what was considered cleaner. About GC, this is not a spec problem, and the optisation was deemed trivial enough for any engine to implement so that it was not a concern when choosing the approach.

Comment: Talking about purity makes no sense in the context of an iterator mutating state on every step, and there's a clear performance advantage to my proposed approach (try modifying the demo slightly to actually make use of the value and you'll see a 2x-4x performance difference depending on the browser). You're entitled to your opinions but I don't buy them unless there's evidence that the developers of the standard shared them.

Comment: @user3026691 Have a look at the link in my edit to the answer.